# Validation Rule with multiple profiles

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I've created a `Validation Rule` on `Lead` that is used to ensure users with profile names `Direct Sale` OR `New Contract` when the users login with those profile my validation rule should fire otherwise without those profile ignore the validation rules.

Without implementing profile logic the below validation works fine

```
NOT(OR(ISPICKVAL(Tech__c, 'IT'),  ISPICKVAL(Tech__c, 'RD'))) == true
```

The above validations check to see the `Tech__c` must be `IT or RD` and i have tested and its working

Problem:

Now when I try to add profile logic nothing works, here is what I have done so far with no success.

```
AND
(
 NOT(OR( 
         ISPICKVAL( Tech__c, "IT "),
         ISPICKVAL( Tech__c,"RD")
      )),
  AND(
         $Profile.Name == "Direct Sale", 
         $Profile.Name == "New Contract"
        )
)
```

I do not get any error and I able to save the validation rule and when I try to login as profile `Direct Sale` and the validation does not fire.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is written to only throw an error when the `$Profile.Name` concurrently matches two distinct values. This case is impossible. Use `OR` instead.

```
AND(
    NOT(OR(
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...)
    )),
    OR(
        $Profile.Name = "Direct Sale",
        $Profile.Name = "New Contract"
    )
)
```

Comment: quick question i can post as new question but the thing i'm trying to fix is, adding an IF condition to it but no errors found but the logic is not working - is that the correct way to do it?`

`IF(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Progress'),
AND(
    NOT(OR(
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...)
    )),
    OR(
        $Profile.Name = "Direct Sale",
        $Profile.Name = "New Contract"
    )
))`

Comment: Is it just one more condition for the outer `AND` clause?

Comment: yes it one more condition so i have check if the pickval status = progress then rest of the condition should apply

Comment: Right, so just add it like the other outer `AND` clauses. `AND(/*status clause*/, /*type clause*/, /*profile clause*/)`